# Safari on IOS doesn’t save cookies

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, cookies

iPhone, latest IOS, Safari.

I do very little web browsing from my phone; in most cases, I just open Safari and search for something. I always had this rather frustrating issue: every time I search for something, Google (which is my default search engine) asks me to accept cookies before displaying search results.

Digging more deeply, I discovered that the problem seems to be related to cookies: Safari just doesn’t seem to save *any* cookie at all; if f.e. I log in to a web site, the next time I go there I will be asked to log in again; anything I do on a web site (including clicking "Accept" on Google's disclaimer) is lost the next time I open it.

The option to block all cookies is *not* enabled.
I'm *not* using private mode.
I'm *not* clearing browser data between sessions.

Why is this happening, and how can I avoid it?

### Example:

I definitely logged in to this very site from my phone to ask this question.
And yet, *from the same phone*, 20 minutes later, I had to log in again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you’re not in private browsing mode.

Tap the tabs button in the bottom right and make sure the Private button in the bottom left is not highlighted with a background. If so, tap the button to leave private browsing.

Comment: Easy first thing to check but just making sure since it’s not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks but I already checked, I also tried turning it on and off again. Added to the question, anyway.

Comment: any adblocker installed? _Block all cookies_ in the Safari preferences is turned off?

Comment: @slartibartfast no and yes.